# Why does my SVM take so long to run?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

I am wondering can anybody spot any reason why this SVM takes so long to run. It takes days to do so where other models such as neural networks, random forest take minutes on the same dataset.

I have `X` as a `df` size `(111855,16)` and y as a `series` size (111855,)

Initially I had my gridsearch looking for a range of C parameters and PC components, but this took a week to run.

I have reduced time by reducing the C parameter in size, choosing a less complex kernel than the default, and removing PCA but still it takes a almost 48 hours to run.

Even taking the code out of the `gridsearch` format does not help.

```
 def SVM(X, y):  
    SVM = SVC(kernel = 'poly')
    pipeline = Pipeline( [('scl', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA()),('clf', SVM)] )
    param_grid= [dict( pca__n_components=[None], clf__C = [0.001]  )]
    grid_search= GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 5)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)   
    return(grid_search.best_estimator_, grid_search.best_score_)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165213/how-much-time-does-take-train-svm-classifier

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the link, but nothing of use in there. I've implemented all the suggestions listed in that thread.

Comment: it is close to O(N^3) where n is number of the data points.

Comment: What hardware are you running on?

Comment: @jbowman i think it is almost impossible to run with 111855 data points in most hardware.

Comment: @jbowman Seemingly it is impossible. The odd thing however is that other models on the same size data run without issue. 

I have an Macbook Pro with 8GB ram, 2.5Ghz i5 processor, and 256GB SSD.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is apply the kernel transformation during preprocessing. This will expand your feature dimension from 16 to something bigger. Then you could use a linear SVM solver that should be a lot faster.

To get even faster, once you've eliminated the need to do the kernel, you can use the sklearn sgd solver with hinge loss to fit the model. When your data size is big then this is much faster than the convex solver used by the SVC function.

Comment: Very interesting. I had never thought about that. I try implement this and see will it speed things up. Thanks for the advice.